# Writing a PowerShell script to copy directory and its contents to all users documents folder

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-ise

First, this is my first REAL question on stack-overflow so here we go:

I am trying to use Get-ChildItem and Copy-Item to copy a directory and its contents to every user-profile that may be on a PC without knowing how many users or their usernames. However, I have run into an illegal character issue whenever I run the script or other variations of what I think are the same way to achieve the result. I think it is because of the wildcard but I do not know how I should circumvent that.

For Example:
Testing the Wildcard:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:Users\*\'
```

I can see all the users and Power-shell Documentation from Microsoft states using the * should allow it so include all items in that folder. But whenever I extend the path to lets say:

```
Copy-Item 'D:\Custom Office Templates' -Recurse -Destination 'C:\Users\*\Documents\' -Force
```

I get an "Illegal Characters in path error."
If I replace that * with an actual username to correct the path I get what I want for a single user.
The same thing happens when trying to use.

```
ForEach-Object {Copy-Item -Path 'D:\Custom Office Templates' -Destination 'C:\users\*\Documents\Custom Office Templates' -Force -Recurse}
```

Thanks you for any assistance given :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-Destination` is read as a literal path, does not understand about wildcards. What you can do is combine what you already have with `Get-ChildItem` using a wildcard on `-Path` with a [delay-bind script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.2#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters) on `-Destination`:

```bash
$source = 'D:\Custom Office Templates'
Get-ChildItem 'C:Users\*\' -Directory |
    Copy-Item -LiteralPath $source -Recurse -Destination {
        Join-Path $_.FullName 'Documents\Custom Office Templates'
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! This has worked. If you don't mind a few confirmation questions from me.

Comment: @VereMyth sure what did you want to know

Comment: To clarify and help me understand how you performed this. You attributed the Path of the item to be copied to the variable $source and then used Get-ChildItem to the 'C: Users\*\' marking it in power-shell as a Directory using -Directory. you then marked the variable $source to Copy-Item with -LiteralPath to make PowerShell treat it as such. Then used Join-Path to join the Directory of folder names retrieved using Get-ChildItem and the rest of the path 'Documents\Custom Office Templates'?

Comment: @VereMyth yes thats correct. First it gets all folders in `C:Users\*` then those objects are passed to `Copy-Item` where we copy the `$source` to a joined path inside the delay-bind scriptblock to each user's `Documents\Custom Office Templates`

Comment: Thank you for the help. This got me out of rut I was in for this and possibly future additions to the script.